# Conditional formating with dates

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I have a big database structured like this:

[image: Picture]

I would need a formula that checks every row (name) and their dates of tests.
If any of the dates is within the current week, the column "Tested this week" would turn green. Same principle with "Tested last week". Basically, I need an overview of every employee's COVID testing of current and last week.

I'm not that good with Excel formulas and I'm having a hard time coming up with functional formula like this. It would save me so many hours in my work.

Any help MUCH appreciated!

Quote Reply
Report

Comment: What day of the week are you using as the first day?

Comment: I haven't managed to setup the formula at all... I'm not that knowledgeable in Excel :/ I'd need a formula that would check if any of the dates are either in Last or Current week (and obviously Monday through Sunday). I managed to make this with other help: =COUNTIF(D2:Z2, ">="&(TODAY()-7)) > 0, but that's for the last 7 days and not very useful for me.

Comment: I apologize, I edited the post and hopefully it's more understandable now...

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all test dates are in the past?